# jquery to update html form with lat and lon

Tags: jquery, html, api, google-maps

I am trying to find the lat and lng using a 'click' event on Google Maps API.  I then want to use JQUERY to update a hidden field in a form with separate lat and long.

my current code looks like this:

```
       function captureLocation() {
         const marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map });
         map.addListener('click', (e) => {
         marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
         map.setCenter(e.latLng);
         const imageLatLng = e.latlng;
         $lat.value = imageLatLng.lat();
         $lng.value = imageLatLng.lng();
        });
       }
```

but it returns as undefined.  Please help.

Comment: What returns? You do not have any return in the code you posted. Also note many calls in Google Map are async

Comment: can you tell us which line returns `undefined`, also can you check for any errors on your browser console?

Answer (score 0):

In the end i used this:

```
      function captureLocation() {
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map
        });
         map.addListener('click', (e) => {
          marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
          map.setCenter(e.latLng);
          const imageLatLng = e.latLng;
          $lat.val(imageLatLng.lat());
          $lng.val(imageLatLng.lng());
        });
      }
```